# 'Could not find file hibernate.cfg.xml' when running after publish my application

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate, deployment

I've 2 problem.

My application is WPF c# app that us MS Access as a database (.dbm file) and NHibernate for connecting.

The first problem is after publishing my app, getting exe file and installing my app, I tried to run the application by I got an exception that it could not find file hibernate.cfg.xml. However, the app worked fine if I run through Visual Studio. That config file is in the same folder of class that call configuration.

In addition, I'm not sure whether my publish method is correct. To publish my WPF app, at the solution explorer I right clicked main project > publish > then follow several steps and end by click 'finish. I haven't seen any config file appear in the publish floder which I expect to see because I want to allow the user to be able to config the path of his database (.dbm file) later. Then this is the second problem.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to move your nHibernate configuration into the app.config

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    ...
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

In your configsections section add

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" requirePermission="false" />
    ...
  <configSections>
<configuration>
```

Or

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"hibernate.cfg.xml"));
```

Answer (score 1):

there's a another place to check.

Open your project properties, go to 'Publish' then click in 'Application Properites'. In this interface you have to check if the file Hibernate.cfg.xml is 'Include' in Publish Status.

Answer (score 0):

After Publishing, do you see the hibernate.cfg.xml in the output directory?

If you added this file in Visual Studio, it may not copy it by default.

Make sure in the file's properties, its type is set to 'Content' and Output as 'Copy'.

Comment: Inside a folder that I got after publishing, I've seen only 'hibernate.cfg.xml.deploy'. Is that the same file? (I also expect to see hibernate.cfg.xml will place in the same folder of .exe file, but it isn't as I hope.) In Visual, the hibernate.cfg.xml file's property was also set to 'content' and 'copy always'. 

Do you have any other ideas to solve my problem?

Comment: If you have your file set as 'Content' and output as 'Copy Always' then the file should always make it to the build folder. Try cleaning your solution by going to BUILD-Clean Solution, then rebuilding it. Also check your solution configuration, I'm not sure how debug/release works with published WPF but your files might be copied to a folder you're not checking correctly.

Comment: I believe that "Copy Always" mean to copy the file to the bin directory, While "Content" means that the publishing operation should copy the file to the same project-relative location (i.e. this is what is used for e.g. .aspx and MVC views).